# How to compose snake case binding tag with go-playground/validator?

Tags: go, validation, snakecasing

As title, since I'm a newbie to golang, I'm a little bit confused of the binding tag for some custom format.

For example,
there's a struct with a few of fields like this

```
type user struct {
   name  `json:"name" binding:"required"`
   hobby `json:"name" binding:"required"`
}
```

and the name field is supposed to support lowercase and underscore only (e.g. john_cage, david)
but after I read the document of validator, still have no idea about that.
[validator github](https://github.com/go-playground/validator)
Is there's any good suggestion or solution for my case? Thanks in advance.

Read the document, google similar questions, try to compose the customer binding tag, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`binding` tag is from `gin`, correct struct tag for `validator` is `validate`. Since there is no vaildation for snake_case, you should make your own. And don't forget to export the fields(`Hobby`, `Name`). If you not, (ex: `hobby`, `name`) validator will ignore the fields.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
)

type user struct {
    Hobby string `json:"name" validate:"required,snakecase"`
}

func main() {
    v := validator.New()
    _ = v.RegisterValidation("snakecase", validateSnakeCase)

    correct := user{"playing_game"}
    Incorrect := user{"playingGame"}

    err := v.Struct(correct)
    fmt.Println(err) // nil

    err = v.Struct(Incorrect)
    fmt.Println(err) // error
}

const allows = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_"

func validateSnakeCase(fl validator.FieldLevel) bool {
    str := fl.Field().String()
    for i := range str {
        if !strings.Contains(allows, str[i:i+1]) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

[Playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/xx8L1Yvop6z)

If you want to register the function via `gin`, [check this out](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#custom-validators)